# Reading information from a worker thread efficiently

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm writing some computer vision software, here's a brief description to help clarify the problem:

- I have 3 cameras, each running at 60fps
- Each camera has it's own thread, to utilise multiple cores
- Each thread waits for a new frame to arrive, does some processing on the image, saves the result and waits for the next frame

My main program creates these thread, using boost, following this tutorial: http://blog.emptycrate.com/node/282

I am currently polling the threads in a tight loop to retrieve the data, e.g.:

```
while(1) {
    for(i=0; i<numCams; i++) {
        result[i] = cam[i]->getResult();
    }

    //do some stuff
}
```

This seems silly.  Is there a standard way of letting the main program know that there is a new result and that it needs to be retrieved?

Thanks!

Comment: Is a signal variable in a watcher thread, an option to signal data has to be read ? But if your looping and function calls isn't expensive, should you worry about it ?

Comment: @DumbCoder - Well..it **is** a busy loop. Back in the single-core days, doing that would lock up the whole system. Even today tieing up a single core permanently isn't exactly playing nice.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need to use [condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) (AKA events).

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be what I need.  However, I'm struggling to work out if it is possible to wait for the 3 threads at once.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jack: See the example in the link I posted, it works for any number of threads.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use synchronization. There are many forms depending on what you're using as a threading API, however the simplest is probably a condition variable.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a thread pool. The number of cameras isn't necessary the same as the optimal number of threads. Thread pool is optimized for performance. Then, you don't need to wait for condition or poll the jobs, you enqueue the jobs (most often it's `std::function<void()>`) in the thread pool, and that job object should perform all the required work. Use binders (`std::bind`) or lambda functions to create a job object.

Comment: As an illustration, you can use GBL library with AsyncHanler sensitive to input data. That will be processed in a thread pool, and GBL will create an easy to use harness for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you are talking to hardware, so you may need to use whatever facilities your camera API provides for asynchronous notification of incomming data. Usually that will be some kind of callback you provide, or occasionally something like a Windows Event handle or Unix signal.

In general if you meant "standard" as in "part of the C++ standard", no. You need to use your OS's facilites for interprocess (or thread) condition signalling.

Note that if we were talking Ada (or Modula-2, or many other modern systems programming languages) the answer would have been "yes". I understand there is some talk of putting concurrency support of some kind into a future C++ standard.

In the meantime, there is the [boost::thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread.html) library for doing this kind of thing. That isn't exactly "standard", but for C++ it is pretty close. I think for what you are trying to do, [condition variables](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref) might be what you want. However, if you read over the whole facility, other simpler designs may occur to you.

Answer (score 0):

I know this sounds a little odd, however consider using a `boost::asio::io_service` it's as close to a threadpool as you get currently. When you've captured an image, you can `post` to this service and the service can then execute a handler asynchronously to handle your image data.